# Code not working after hosting on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, executable

I am working on a MVC project. Here I am trying to get the elements of some other site. To get elements I am using `WebBrowser` Class object and the syntax goes like this :

```
var a = wb.Document.GetElementById("_menu__tableMenu").GetElementsByTagName("a");<br>
HtmlElement x = a[2];
```

where wb is instance of `WebBrowser` class
This code works perfectly on my development machine and in my company's network (When hosted in one of our staging servers)
But when I try to host it on client's hosting server it simply throws "Object reference not set to an instance " issue.

After logging errors I found out that this error is for  `HtmlElement x = a[2];` because array a doesn't have any item. But I am not able to understand why is it working this way where as all the elements I am looking for, exist.

I think that it can be a synchronization issue

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

You may try using the html agility pack: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ I think it has better handling of DOM in various situations.

Does wb.Document.GetElementById("*menu*_tableMenu") return anything, or is it also null?

Can you please show the code where you make your web request?

Comment: After digging a bit I found that wb.Document.GetElementById("menu_tableMenu") is returning null because wb control is still in previous page. I traced wb.Document property and it returned login page html of the website I am trying to visit.

Comment: Here is the code:
wb.DocumentCompleted += new webBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
wb.Navigate("LOGIN URL");
wb.Document.GetElementById("ctrlUserName").InnerText = "USERNAME";
wb.Document.GetElementById("ctrlPassword").InnerText = "PASSWORD";
wb.Document.GetElementById("btnLogin").InvokeMember("Click");

Comment: Here is the code:
wb.DocumentCompleted += new webBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
wb.Navigate("LOGIN URL");
wb.Document.GetElementById("ctrlUserName").InnerText = "USERNAME";
wb.Document.GetElementById("ctrlPassword").InnerText = "PASSWORD";
wb.Document.GetElementById("btnLogin").InvokeMember("Click");

Comment: //Now default page to traverse which is not working


var a = wb.Document.GetElementById("_menu__tableMenu");

//Now since wb.Document is still returning login page html so //"menu__tableMenu" is not there but I am not sure why is it return //login page html while on development and staging server it works //perfectly

Comment: one more thing here is that URL I am trying to call is HTTPS not Http. I guess it can be issue.